# fake a request in Django

Tags: django, view

I have a Django equipped with Tastypie and under REST style it's not easy to combine objectes of different types together, so I'm thinking if it's posible to provide a special view for combining response of several REST urls into a bigger JSON object and return to client. The url may look like,

> http:// domain.com /combined_view/?p={rest url 1...}&p={rest url
>   2...}&p={rest url 3...}

and returned JSON would be,

> [ {response of rest url 1...}, 
>     {response of rest url 2...}, 
>     {response of rest url 3...}, 
>     ... 
>   ]

The question is, inside a normal django view, how can I fake a request object, and process it into a response object? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Calling your own RESTful API from inside your view is a waste of resources. Directly access the objects using the database ORM instead.

Also unrelated Resources/Objects are supposed to be not combined together. If you think that the models should be combined together then maybe your model needs to take care of it and have a relation combining the two.

And to answer your question directly, you can call your urls using [httplib2](http://bitworking.org/projects/httplib2/doc/html/libhttplib2.html) and parse the response.

Comment: One example of such page is a native view containing a banner and a list of articles, which have no relation to each other. In Django, they are of different modules. So I found that using something like a proxy to fetch them in one request is meaningful. Using httplib2 is ok but Django is under a well loosely-coupled design, and I guess it's possible to fake a request and gain response. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at Template Inheritance (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance) for banner? Restful interfaces are not really intended to be called from inside your views. That's bad design.

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to reconsider whatever it is that your doing, because whatever answer we give you here is bound to go directly against the resourceful design of REST interfaces.

If you have `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` models and you create equivalent resources for them, it's impossible to generate a request that's going to return a mixed collection of `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` resources, unless these are nested resources in a joint relationship.

Your either not thinking in a resourceful manner or don't need to, but definitely don't turn RESTful architectures into something they haven't been designed for.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree that LOOKS not restful but it's just considered as a proxy helping to reduce request times for some read requests, which may help much on a mobile device. other wise it need to send out several requests to provide data for a mobile page. Logically it's still restful interface.

Comment: If your going down that path, why create a separate request at all? Why don't just just dump the JSON data in the initial HTML response?